# Change image during scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, each

I would like to change image when I scroll on a sidebar. I use a each function and scrollto.

The main part of the code :

```
$('.image-content').each(function(index, element) {
  var imagePosition = $(element).offset().top;
  var imageDefault = $('.image-content:eq(0)').offset().top;
  var called = false;

  $('.sidebar').scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $('.sidebar').scrollTop();

    if ( scrollPosition >= imagePosition ) {
      if (!called) {
        called = true;
        coverImage(index, element);
      }
    } else if ( scrollPosition <= imageDefault ) {
      // if (!called) {
        // called = true;
        defaultcover();
      // }
    }
  });
});
```

I created a **called** variable to do not repeat the function call (coverImage) otherwise it change all the time the image link. At the first scroll, it works well, but when I scroll to the top, it didn't works again, because the called variable is set to true. *(I don't want to use any plugin)*

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/74etJ/7/)

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the

```
  called = true;
```

from

```
 if ( scrollPosition >= imagePosition ) {
      if (!called) {
        called = true;
        coverImage(index, element);
      }
 }
```

Then whats wrong? Because it seems to be working then.

Comment: Yep it's working, but it call during all the time I scroll on the image the coverImage function. And it make the transition so slow. When the image link is changed, I don't want to call the function again, that's why I tried to create a called variable.

Comment: if ( scrollPosition <= imageDefault ) {
in this statement, add the line called = false;

Comment: Indeed, it's a little bit better. But now, when I am at the bottom the page, and decide to scroll up, I would like to change also the image, and not be forced to scroll to the top to set the called variable to false.

Comment: On which event do you want it to change? Because if it is a manual one, you wouldn't have to check for called, for it would only trigger once causing no problem with lag.

Comment: As you can see on my jsfidddle, when the last cat image is display on fullscreen, and if I scroll up to the previous cat image, I want to display on fullscreen. But actually, I need to scroll to the top of the page, to restore the called variable value. The aim of the script is to change automatically of images when I am scrolling on the sidebar.